# Oracle.ManagedDataAccess reads DST dates incorrectly

Tags: .net, oracle, date, dst

I am writing a .Net application that runs on top of an Oracle 11.2.0.2.0 database that stores dates in columns of type "TIMESTAMP(6) WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE".  When there is a date stored into the column and it falls within DST, the date is read incorrectly when using the Oracle.ManagedDataAccess library.  It appears to always write/update dates correctly.  Also, when using the Oracle.DataAccess library, it always handles the dates correctly.

In my example I am using timezone 'America/New_York' and date/time of 08/01/2014 12:00:00.  Here is a snippet of code that reads the date incorrectly:

```
IDbConnection cxn = new Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleConnection(ConnStr);
// Using the following library works correctly: 
// IDbConnection cxn = new Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection(ConnStr);
cxn.Open();

var cmd = cxn.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "alter session set time_zone='America/New_York'";
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT TEST_DATE FROM TEST_TABLE WHERE ROWNUM=1";
return (DateTime)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

When the column is updated with value 08/01/2014 12:00:00, it is read as 08/01/2014 11:00:00.  If I use a date that does not fall within DST (such as 12/01/2014 12:00:00), it reads the date correctly.  Any ideas on this?  I have been searching all over but have not found any documentation on this issue.  I may have to switch back to the Oracle.DataAccess, but was hoping to avoid it.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle.ManagedDataAccess is still quite new, so you also get always the "newest" bugs.

There are others ways to define your current session timezone, maybe one of the following works.

- Usage of **OracleGlobalization** class:

  ```
  this.Connection = new OracleConnection();
  this.Connection.ConnectionString = ...
  this.Connection.Open();
  OracleGlobalization info = this.Connection.GetSessionInfo();
  info.TimeZone = "America/New_York";
  this.Connection.SetSessionInfo(info);
  ```

  Test this very carefully, my experience with `OracleGlobalization` is quite bad. Test also `this.Connection.OpenWithNewPassword(...);`, not only `this.Connection.Open();`. When I used `OpenWithNewPassword` my application was crashing without any error (even while debugging in Visual Studio!)
- Set `ORA_SDTZ` as Environment variable in your system.
- Set timezone in your Registry, it is a String Value for `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ORACLE\KEY_{YOUR_ORACLE_HOME_NAME}\ORA_SDTZ`, e.g.

  For a x64 (64 bit) Application

  ```
  Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

  [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ORACLE\KEY_OraClient11g_home1]
  "ORA_SDTZ"="America/New_York"
  ```

  For a x86 (32 bit) Application

  ```
  Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

  [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\ORACLE\KEY_OraClient11g_home1]
  "ORA_SDTZ"="America/New_York"
  ```

  **Note**, ODP.NET Managed Driver does not read any Registry values, so this is more as information for other drivers!

Comment: I am running into the same issue. The first idea (OracleGlobalization) does not work since the error is thrown on .Open() already. The Env variable seems to have no effect. Registry key is also not an option in my case since im running .NET Core in Linux. Any other ideas? Thanks!