# System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'oci' when deployed to a Docker Linux container

Tags: c#, docker, dll, asp.net-core-mvc, system.data.oracleclient

I tried to use [System.Data.OracleClient](https://github.com/tonyrapozo/System.Data.OracleClient) to connect with oracle db. My .net core application works well in vs2017 and IIS, but when I deploy to a Linux Container and run a part that gets a connection from the database I get this error:

System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'oci': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E) at System.Data.OracleClient.Oci.OciCalls.OciNativeCalls.OCIEnvCreate(IntPtr& envhpp, OciEnvironmentMode mode, IntPtr ctxp, IntPtr malocfp, IntPtr ralocfp, IntPtr mfreep, Int32 xtramem_sz, IntPtr usrmempp)

When I tried to run the run the part again, the error became:

System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
at System.Data.OracleClient.OracleConnectionPool.GetConnection () [0x00000] in :0
at System.Data.OracleClient.OracleConnection.Open () [0x00000] in :0

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

update:
  I removed [System.Data.OracleClient](https://github.com/tonyrapozo/System.Data.OracleClient) and used [Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Core](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Core/),the error gone.
  It's important to note that when use Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Core version 2.18.3 ,you must set an environment variable called TZ to docker linxu container but in version 2.12.0-beta3 TZ is not necessary,for detail you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53510011/asp-net-core-docker-container-using-oracle-managed-driver-core-throws-ora-00604).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though the dependencies only show `netstandard 2.0` I doubt the package works on `.net core` linux. It seems to have some dependencies on the `.net famework`. There's also an open issue here [Unable to load DLL 'oci'](https://github.com/tonyrapozo/System.Data.OracleClient/issues/8).

Also the one on the `ms docs` is only available for `.net framework`. See here: [System.Data.OracleClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oracleclient)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion,I have browsed the open issue and docs.