# ASP.NET MVC application ORA-01882: timezone region not found

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oracle, visual-studio-2017

I'm  trying to have access to an Oracle Database from a ASP.NET MVC application, when I try to connect to db I get the following error:

ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1
ORA-01882: timezone region not found

env: Visual studio 2017
Oracle 11g
provider: odp.net managed

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Hm8p.png)

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9156379/ora-01882-timezone-region-not-found

Comment: i read the solution and it not solve my problem, thx

Comment: take a look on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53510011/asp-net-core-docker-container-using-oracle-managed-driver-core-throws-ora-00604. Seems to be the same issue.